# HTML no longer working in JLabel (and other components)

Tags: java, applet

I have a java applet that I've written and have been running it for quite a while. In the applet I have a bunch of JLabels that use HTML in their text content (which is allowed, and has been working for years). The main reason I use HTML is to allow line breaks in JLabels.

**The issue:** fairly recently the JLabels that have HTML in them (some don't) stopped displaying their text. I think it might have something to do with the recent java update (Java SE 6 Update 22, on 2010-Oct-12) not 100 percent sure, but the problems did seem to start around then. Maybe a bug has been introduced? or feature removed?

I tried with a JEditorPane and seemed to have the same issues when the content was HTML.

Also something important to note is that the first time you load the applet (first time your java runtime starts) it works FINE, but if you refresh the webpage then it has the issues as described.

Does anyone have similar issues? anyone have any insights? or am I just doing something dumb?

I made a very simple test applet and I can reproduce the issues with 100% regularity (remembering that the first time the runtime loads it will work fine, only successive refreshes will cause the issues):

[HelloWorldApplet.java]

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class HelloWorldApplet extends JApplet
{
    public void init()
    {
        this.add(new JLabel("Hello Everybody (Text)"), java.awt.BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.add(new JLabel("<html><body>Hello Everybody (HTML)</body></html>"), java.awt.BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }
}
```

[HellowWorldApplet.html]

```
<html>
<title>A Test</title>
<body>
    <applet code="HelloWorldApplet.class" width="320" height="120">
        You need Java
    </applet>
</body>
</html>
```

PS. I've been mainly testing using Chrome but I did breifly try in IE 8 also.
Also I (obviously) have the latest Java SE 6 update 22 installed as my run time, and have the matching update for my JDK. I compile the above test applet using simply: "javac HelloWorldApplet.java"

Comment: I just did another test where I spawn a new Thread which loops and updates the labels every second, showing an increasing int count. When the int is even I update the label with HTML and when the int is odd I update the label with Text (No HTML)... as I expected when updated with HTML the label shows nothing, and when updated with just Text it displays the text correctly. Something is wrong with HTML. It seems hard to believe no one else is having these issues?

Comment: Also calling .putClientProperty("html.disable", Boolean.TRUE) on the label will cause the html to display (but of course it will display as text, ie show the html itself rather than interpreting it - which isn't what is desired). But just another proof that the JLabel is drawing correctly it just isn't interpreting the html.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wasted an afternoon looking for the cause of this, see the following bug report https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6993691

The workaround in the bug report is:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.html.parser.ParserDelegator;

public class HelloWorldApplet extends JApplet {
    public void init() {
       ParserDelegator workaround = new ParserDelegator();
       applet.add(new JLabel("Hello Everybody (Text)"), java.awt.BorderLayout.NORTH);
       applet.add(new JLabel("<html>Hello Everybody (HTML)</html>"),  java.awt.BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }
}
```

Comment: Aww yes! Thanks a bunch, sorry you spent your afternoon on this but I'm super appreciative. I tried looking through the bugs database but didn't find that one. At least it was a bug and I wasn't going crazy. Thanks again, yay.

Comment: actually i should thank you :) i stumbled upon this behavior when extending an ancient (mainly AWT based) applet, i had been thinking what i had screwed up coding. thankfully i found your post a few hours later and then another one on stackoverflow linking to the java bugtracker...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds from the description like a threading issue.

Unfortunately applets are not constructed or have their lifecycle methods called on the AWT Event Dispatch Thread (EDT).

Technically your constructor and `init` code should be executed inside `java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait`.

Comment: I've simplified the example above (from the original), just for simplicity sake. Then, in response to your answer, I tried wrapping the two this.add() calls with an invokeAndWait(new Runnable(){public void run(){...}}) call and it still has the same issues.

Comment: I also find it funny that everything works fine with a fresh runtime but then the issue happens on successive runs within the running runtime. I would think a threading issue would always happen - though  I could be incorrect about that.

Comment: @devlop Threading is about timing. First time initialisation can be slow, so there is plenty of scope for the timings to be completely different.

Comment: Also of note is that there are two JLabels one works fine the other doesn't, both identical (as shown in the example code) except only for the string content: one being just text the other HTML (only the HTML one doesn't work).