# Using HTML in my JLabel

Tags: html, colors, append

Okay so I figured out the whole color business using HTML, but now when I put it in my Jlabel its not working! Might it have anything to do with the fact that i am using getText() from a TextArea to set the text of my Jlabel? Here's my code:

```
String air = "<html>\n" +
            "<ul><font color=blue>blue</font>\n" +
            "</ul>\n";
```

...

```
JLabel jl = new JLabel();
jl.setSize(700,700);
frame.add(jl);
jl.setText(environment.getText());
```

I get this....

```
<html><ul><font color=blue> text </font></ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code and it's work properly.
Can you post complete code ? Are you running java applet ?
I found similar issue in here : [HTML no longer working in JLabel (and other components)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330602/html-no-longer-working-in-jlabel-and-other-components).
Hope it's can help you.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class JLabelSample extends JFrame {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JLabelSample();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    String air = "<html>\n" + "<ul><font color=blue>blue</font>\n"
            + "</ul>\n";
    JTextArea area = new JTextArea(air);

    frame.add(area);

    JLabel jl = new JLabel();
    jl.setSize(100, 100);
    frame.add(jl);

    jl.setText(area.getText());

}
```

}